# How to enable Imagick in MAMP 4 (Lite)?

Tags: mamp, imagick

I am trying to enable Image Magick in MAMP 4 (Lite, not Pro) for PHP 7.1.0.
Everything I have found regarding this, is for MAMP 3.

It states, that I have to uncomment the line:
`;extension=imagick.so`

The guide said, I have to uncomment it this file:
`/Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.1.0/php.ini`

My `phpinfo()` says the loaded configuration file is:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/conf/php.ini`

I uncommented both and restarted the server, but the extension does not get loaded.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the issue.

The `extension_dir` inside the php.ini does point to the non existing folder:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/`

The only folder that exists is:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/`

I don’t know why this is pointing to an older folder, but after changing it to the new one, Imagick gets loaded.